# Unity trigger method does nothing

Tags: unity, c#, physics

I have the following script on my object:

```
public class PlayMyCube : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Animator myAnimationController;

    private void onTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player")) {
            myAnimationController.SetBool("playSpin2", true);
        }
    } 

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player")) {
            myAnimationController.SetBool("playSpin2", false);
        }
    }
}
```

When the player character is inside the first cube's trigger, my second cube should play a spinning animation. When they leave, the second cube should stop.

But what happens in the game now is, when the character runs into the trigger, it does nothing.

I have configured my trigger object like this:

[image: Unity Inspector Screenshot]

I have configured the object that should spin like this:

[image: Unity Inspector Screenshot]

And configured the Animation Controller like this:

[image: Animation control graph]

[image: Transition into spin]

[image: Transition out of spin]

And configured my Player object like this:

[image: Unity Inspector for Player]

What can I do to make this animation play when the player is inside the trigger?

Answer (score 2):

The method is called `OnTriggerEnter` (uppercase O)

What you wrote in your script is `onTriggerEnter` (lowercase o)

Identifiers in C# are case-sensitive, so these are two completely different functions as far as the compiler/engine is concerned. When it tries to call `OnTriggerEnter`, it discovers there's no method on your script with exactly that name, so it does nothing.

Please be careful to type your scripts correctly, and proofread your code for typos.

You can find this class of error faster in future by using a breakpoint or `Debug.Log` to determine whether the method is even being called when you expect. That will let you isolate the problem and find your own answers quickly. Or, if the answer still eludes you, it will at least help you ask a more concise question: all the extra detail you showed with the animator here isn't relevant to the problem, if the `onTriggerEnter` method is never being called.